# Search in array of objects in JavaScript in all keys values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can somebody give an example of good performance optimized search function in array of objects in javascript. I am trying to make a serachbar which returns a matched value in array of objects but i can only make it to return value if it match a certain key in my example is 'name'. Want to make a search which returns values in all the keys. This is my example object, and this is my search function. Thanks in advance

`{{name: 'John Smith', email: 'johnsmith@smth.com', organization: 'Nike'},{name: 'John Doe', email: 'johndoe@smth.com', organization: 'Sony'}}`

```
filteredItems() {
  return this.items.filter(item => {
   return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) > -1)
})}
```

Comment: I did not downvote your question, but some tips. show us what you have tried, and what did not work when you tried those things. right now, the question is simply asking for a solution, which is not what stack is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const filteredItems = () => {
  const regex = new RegExp(this.filter, 'i');
  return this.items.filter((item) => Object.values(item).find((value) => regex.test(value)));
};
```

I believe this should be somewhat optimised for your needs.